# Manipulating a resultSet for multiple inputs on a table

Tags: java, html, sql, resultset

I have worked with this a couple of times, and got it to work using an Array, but I wanted to try it in a different way.  Basically I have a query that would give me these DB results:

```
 ID      CODE       DESCRIPTION1       POS      SORTER      DATE
----    ------    ----------------    -----    --------    ------
WEB     2003SP      Spring 2003         1          1      1-1-2003
WEB     2003FL      Fall 2003           2          1      8-1-2003
WEB     2003SU      Summer 2003         3          1      5-1-2003
WEB     2003Q1     Quarter 1 2003       4          2      1-1-2003
WEB     2003Q2     Quarter 2 2003       5          2      4-1-2003
WEB     2003Q3     Quarter 3 2003       6          2      7-1-2003
WEB     2003Q4     Quarter 4 2003       7          2      10-1-2003
```

So, what I was wanting to do now, is use these results to populate my HTML table.  Here is how I was looking at populating the table (take a look at the comments in the code):

```
   <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Terms</td>
      <td>Date</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">UG Terms</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>All Sections</td>
    <tr>
      <td>  <!-- HERE I WOULD WANT TO PRINT ALL TERMS WHERE SORTER = '1' --></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Other Sections</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- HERE I WOULD WANT TO PRINT ALL TERMS WHERE SORTER = '1' --></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Winter</td>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- HERE I WOULD WANT TO PRINT ALL TERMS WHERE SORTER = '1' and REPRESENTATION.substring(0,5) = 'Spring' --></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Summer</td>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- HERE I WOULD WANT TO PRINT ALL TERMS WHERE SORTER = '1' and REPRESENTATION.substring(0,5) = 'Summer' --></td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">Other Terms</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>All Sections</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><!-- HERE I WOULD WANT TO PRINT ALL TERMS WHERE SORTER = '2' --></td>
    <tr>
  </table>
```

So again, Where the comments are is how I want to fill out the table,  I am thinking this is possible, and I was just wondering how to go about doing this.  Thanks for the help, and if more info is needed, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do different queries and use the results to populate the different parts of your table:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE SORTER = '1'
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE WHERE SORTER = '1' and REPRESENTATION.substring(0,5) = 'Spring'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE WHERE SORTER = '1' and REPRESENTATION.substring(0,5) = 'Winter'
```

or you could go with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
```

and then you loop over the results and create different Result Sets (Pseudocode):

```
while(rs.next()){
   String a = rs.getString('SORTER');
   if('1'.equals(a)){ 
     if(/*RepSubstring.equals('Spring')*/){ listSpring.add(rs.getRow());}
     else if(/*RepSubstring.equals('Winter')*/){listWinter.add(rs.getRow());}   
     else{list.add(rs.getRow());}
   }
}
```

The three lists are ArrayList or implement List interface.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I was just curious if it could be done without using ArrayLists.  I did think about having multiple queries, and then having multiple resultSets, but is that considered bad practice, or will the page run slowly/slower?

Comment: Actually IMHO it is best using multiple queries, it makes your code neater, and you can just optimize them as needed if you fear you could have efficiency problems.